# Does normalization of projective varieties preserve very ampleness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ample-bundles

Let $f:\tilde{X} \to X$ be a normalization of projective variety. Let $L$ be a very ample line bundle on $X$. Is $f^*L$ a very ample line bundle on $\tilde{X}$? If not true in general, is there any dimension restriction on $X$ for which this is true?

Comment: Not in general, because the sections of $f^*L$ need not  separate points. E.g. take a nodal curve in the plane, and then normalize.

Comment: Never, sort of definitionally, unless $X$ is normal . It does stay ample.

Comment: I don't understand the two comments above. Take $\mathcal O(1)$ on $\mathbb P^2$ and restrict to a nodal cubic $X$. Then $f^* L$ is degree $3$ on $\tilde X$, hence very ample, no?

Comment: OK, yes, my 2nd sentence was not carefully formulated. I was thinking of a scenario along the lines of abx 2).

Comment: Mine too :) .  I think abx took the time to think out the question more thoroughly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) There are certainly many cases where $f^*L$ is still very ample: e.g. if $X$ is an irreducible curve, any line bundle  on $X$ of degree $\geq 2g(\tilde{X} )+1$ will have this property.

2) A typical situation where $f^*L$ is not very ample is when $H^0(\tilde{X},f^*L )\cong H^0(X,L)$. For instance, take for $X$ a curve with one ordinary double point $s$, and $L=\omega _X(-p)$, $p$ a smooth point of $X$. Then $f^*L=\omega _{\tilde{X}}(s'+s''-\tilde{p} )$, where $s',s''$ are the 2 points of $\tilde{X} $ above  $s$ and $\tilde{p} $ the point above $p$. Riemann-Roch gives $h^0(f^*L)= g(\tilde{X} )=h^0(L)$ (I choose $p$ so that $h^0(s'+s''-\tilde{p} )=0$).

I think there is no simple criterion allowing to decide which situation occurs, you have to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you indicate how to proceed in the case of irreducible surfaces with at most rational singularities (at isolated points).

Comment: But aren't these surfaces already normal?